# Powershell ErrorAction not silent

Tags: powershell

I've got a PS script that looks for the Office15 folder on computers on our network. For the most part, the script works as intended. In fact, this is just me being picky. I set `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, but the error messages when the Office15 folder is not found still appear on screen. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or just don't really understand what my script is doing.

```
$filePath = "\\"+$computer+"\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\"
$listing = Get-ChildItem $filePath | where-object { $_.name -eq "Office15" } | Select-Object Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

With this script as-is, I get errors like the following:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\COMPNAME\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\someGuy\bootTime\checkOffice.ps1:16 char:20
+ $listing = Get-ChildItem $filePath | where-object { $_.name -eq "Office1 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\COMPNAME\c$\Pr...crosoft Office\:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I pump all of the valid results into a text file, so the other parts of the script work just fine, and I get the expected results otherwise. I'm only really interested in learning what I might be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the error action to `gci`:

```
$listing = Get-ChildItem $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where-object { $_.name -eq "Office15" } | Select-Object Name
```